# Why isn't xargs running one command per line for this use case?

Tags: terminal, command-line

My overall task is to ping each EC2 server I happen to be connected to.

I am using this command to do that:

`netstat -W | grep ec2 | cut -d " " -f 18 | sort -u | cut -d "." -f 1,2,3,4 | xargs -0 -p "ping -c 10"`

It outputs the right output, but is not calling `xargs` per line:

```
ping -c 10 ec2-107-20-154-211.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-107-20-169-186.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-13-58-191-91.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws
ec2-18-204-248-223.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-18-207-50-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-18-234-32-173.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-34-192-54-86.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-34-195-196-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-34-206-216-146.compute-1.amazonaws.com
?...^C
```

The written explanation of each step is:

1. Run netstat with the `-W` flag to get complete FQDNs and not short hostnames
2. `grep` for ec2
3. `cut` the output to get just the hostname column
4. `sort` unique hostnames
5. `cut` the hostname again to drop the portnumber from the end e.g. `ec2-1-2-3.amazon.com.80` -> `ec2-1-2-3.amazon.com`
6. `xargs` the output to `ping` each host ten times

I think I am running into an issue with either the OS X variant of `xargs` because piping the same output to `wc -l` shows eight lines:

```
netstat -W | grep ec2 | cut -d " " -f 18 | sort -u | cut -d "." -f 1,2,3,4 | wc -l
       8
```

I am focusing on the xargs aspect here. That is the only part of this task that is not apparently working.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself with:

`netstat -W | grep ec2 | cut -d " " -f 18 | sort -u | cut -d "." -f 1,2,3,4 | xargs -p -L 1 ping -c 10`

It provides the expected eight calls to `ping`, one for each host found.

I *think* this solution works because the `-L` flag limits it to one line per command.